# Crush the CRUD, Just POST-it: Is using POST for all operations a better option than implementing CRUD?

Tags: rest, crud

Crud POST, DELETE, PUT and GET, does not seem to fit majority of situations.

It feels cumbersome/forced/unnatural to have CRUD interface for all objects, bloats the number of operations, also it does not deliver the promise of 'self documentation' and 'consistency'.

What are the pros/cons if I just use POST, naming the endpoints in domain-specific language,  for all db operations?

Comment: We did, and we still do - it's SOAP

Comment: SOAP is all XML though - I love the JSON approach with REST, it's just the CRUDdiness.

Comment: Nobody prevents you from mirroring SOAP with JSON over POST

Comment: You're mixing your distaste with RESTful services with CRUD.  But 'persuade me' types of debates and discussions doesn't fit well on stackoverflow. It's a good discussion, but if there can't be an accepted answer to it, then it doesn't belong.

Comment: Also, don't let yourself get fooled by the Angular/Vue/React hipsters - SOAP is still widely in use, especially in enterprise environments

Comment: I realise there are other alternatives I could use - the reason I'm asking now is because I've been presented with an interface to call that's really twisting to jump through the CRUD hoops and I'm wondering why anybody ever bothers with it?

Comment: I don't know about your past experiences but you will soon learn that there are a lot of bad developers and a lot of bad software out there :-)

Comment: @Smutje - that's actually really comforting and is probably the answer I'm looking for, I've been assuming I'm just not seeing what's so clever about it because I'm thick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So please tell me, why don't we just burn the whole pile and use POST requests with meaningful names and parameters in the body for everything?

SOAP did that.  So too does gRPC.  It's not an approach without merit.

But what you lose is the ability to use general purpose components that take advantage of the semantics promised by the other HTTP methods.

For example, in a world of just POST, you lose Google -- there's no way to build up a picture of the web, because you can't know which POST requests are effectively read only.

General purpose components can't autonomously handle unreliable networks, because the don't have the metadata necessary to distinguish which messages are safe to resend and which are not.

Remote authoring tools are probably off the table as well, because you don't have a general purpose language for describing your local edits to the server.

You lose the ability to intelligently interrogate a resource about which methods make sense.  Or to distinguish requests for metadata from requests for the entire representation.

You lose the ability to offload work to a general purpose appliance, because that appliance would necessarily need to be able to correctly interpret the semantics of the payload in order to do the write thing.

> I've been presented with an interface to call that's really twisting to jump through the CRUD hoops and I'm wondering why anybody ever bothers with it?

Because [transporting documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) is a utility.  Doing that in a standardized way allows us to invest our design capital in ways that promise a much higher yield (namely, delivering value to the business).

As usual, consider your question in the context of the world wide web.  Why do we need GET?  Because it allows us to offload read behaviors to caches without interfering with operations that must be delivered to the origin server.  HEAD gives us a mechanism to refresh our metadata, without also fetching the resource itself (convenient when the resource is large).  PUT and DELETE give us the ability to make changes to our web site remotely.  OPTIONS gives us the ability to discover which methods are supported by a resource.  PATCH (a late comer to the party) gives us a convenient way to apply *small* changes to *large* resources, reducing in some cases the bandwidth required to make a change.

Of course, you will also have noticed that the world wide web used POST; rather a lot, in fact.  And that's OK -- see [Roy Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST only becomes an issue when it is used in a situation for which some other method is ideally suited: e.g., retrieval of information that should be a representation of some resource (GET), complete replacement of a representation (PUT), or any of the other standardized methods that tell intermediaries something more valuable than “this may change something.”
>
> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

I'd recommend taking an hour or so to watch this 2014 presentation by Stefan Tilkov  [REST: I Don't Think It Means What You Think It Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).  If you have a second hour, go look at the [Webber 2011 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

> there are a lot of bad developers and a lot of bad software out there

Somewhat more generously, there's a lot of [cargo cult](http://calteches.library.caltech.edu/51/2/CargoCult.htm) REST out there, with practitioners following "best practices" that aren't actually motivated by principles.  It's just one big [game of telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).